# Выход за границы массива при чтении файла + оптимизация

Tags: c#

Функция на чтение большого текстового файла, вывод работы функции представляет собой: смещение/разделитель/байтовое представление восьми символов/разделитель/байтовое представление следующих восьми символов/представление 16 байтовых символов по таблице ASCII. Проблема в строке с комментарием (ошибка указана в комментарии) + программа должна работать с большими файлами (начиная с 4 гб и выше), поэтому если увидите вариант оптимизации функции, смело предлагайте.Ошибка выводится при работе не с каждым файлом,некоторые отрабатывают нормально.

Одна из строчек вывода:

```
000010: 50-4B-03-04-14-00-06-00 ||| 08-00-00-00-21-00-32-91 ||| PK..........!.2"
```

```
public static string FileProcess(string filename)
{
    var specialSybmol = (byte)'.';
    var fs = new FileStream(filename,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
    var array = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(array, 0, array.Length);
    int offset = 0;
    var bt1 = new byte[8];
    var bt2 = new byte[8];
    StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder(100000);

    for(int i = 0; i < array.Length;)
    {
        outputString.Append((offset * 10).ToString().PadLeft(8, '0') + "::: ");
        offset++;
        Array.Copy(array,i, bt1, 0, Math.Min(8, fs.Length - i));
        if(array.Length > i + 8)
            Array.Copy(array,i + 8,bt2,0, Math.Min(8, fs.Length - i));//System.ArgumentException: "Длина исходного массива недостаточна. Проверьте значения srcIndex и длины, а также нижние границы массива."
        for (int j = 0; j < bt1.Length; j++)
        {
            if (bt1[j] < 0x20 || bt1[j] > 0x7f) bt1[j] = specialSybmol;
            if (bt2[j] < 0x20 || bt2[j] > 0x7f) bt2[j] = specialSybmol;
        }
        outputString.Append($"{BitConverter.ToString(bt1)} ||| {BitConverter.ToString(bt2)} ||| ");
        outputString.Append($"{Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bt1)}{Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bt2)}\n");
        i += 16;

    }
    fs.Close();
    return outputString.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Читать файл кусками по несколько десятков килобайт. В выводе я вижу `\n` - значит метод вполне может возвращать `IEnumerable<string>` вместо `string`.

Comment: Покажите пример текста, который получается в итоге.

Comment: В WinForms есть [ByteViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.byteviewer?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) - показывает данные в желаемом формате.

Answer (score 0):

Сперва несколько замечаний по существующему коду.

Ресурсы нужно освобождать, поэтому следует использовать [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement):

```
using var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

При этом `fs.Close();` можно убрать - стрим закроется сам, причём даже в случае исключения.

---

Файловый поток у вас используется для одной цели: прочитать данные полностью в массив:

```
var array = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(array, 0, array.Length);
```

Гораздо проще это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
var array = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
```

При этом `FileStream` полностью убираем из кода.
А там, где у вас используется `fs.Length`, пишем `array.Length`.

---

`offset * 10` - на самом деле, умножать нужно на 16 - ведь именно по шестнадцать байт суммарно вы читаете в два массива `bt1`, `bt2`.
Это число является адресом и выводить его нужно в шестнадцатеричном виде.

```
(offset * 16).ToString("X")
```

К тому же можно избавиться от вызова `PadLeft(8, '0')`, добавив 8 в строку формата: `ToString("X8")`.

---

Во вложенном цикле `for (int j` вы заменяете символы за пределами видимых ASCII на `specialSybmol` до вызова `BitConverter.ToString`. В результате в итоговую строку попадают токены `2E` вместо реальных кодов.
Вот так будет правильно:

```
outputString.Append($"{BitConverter.ToString(bt1)} ||| {BitConverter.ToString(bt2)} ||| ");
for (int j = 0; j < bt1.Length; j++)
{
    if (bt1[j] < 0x20 || bt1[j] > 0x7f) bt1[j] = specialSybmol;
    if (bt2[j] < 0x20 || bt2[j] > 0x7f) bt2[j] = specialSybmol;
}        
outputString.Append($"{Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bt1)}{Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bt2)}\n");
```

---

---

> программа должна работать с большими файлами (начиная с 4 гб и выше)

Это невозможно в текущей реализации. Это ограничено и максимальной длиной массива [Array.Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=net-7.0) и ещё больше максимальным размером итоговой строки. Каждые 16 байт файла превращаются в 81 юникодный символ (что составляет 162 байта). Длина строки [String.Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.length?view=net-7.0) опять-таки ограничена значением `int`.

---

---

Решить это можно, изменив возвращаемый тип на `IEnumerable<string>`.

```
IEnumerable<string> ProcessFile(string filename)
{
    var specialSybmol = (byte)'.';
    var buffer = new byte[16];
    var edited = new byte[16];
    int offset = 0;
    using var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = fs.ReadAtLeast(buffer.AsSpan(), 16, throwOnEndOfStream: false)) > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
        {
            edited[i] = buffer[i] < 0x20 || buffer[i] > 0x7f ? specialSybmol: buffer[i];
        }

        string line = $@"{offset:X8} : {
            BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0, int.Min(8, bytesRead)),-23} | {
            BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 8, int.Max(0, bytesRead - 8)),-23} | {
            Encoding.ASCII.GetString(edited, 0, bytesRead)}";

        yield return line;
        offset += 16;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
foreach (var line in ProcessFile("test.txt"))
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Здесь снова пришлось вернуться к использованию `FileStream`, ведь мы не хотим читать весь файл сразу в память. Читаем кусками по 16 байт.
Я использовал метод [Stream.ReadAtLeast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readatleast?view=net-7.0), который появился в .NET7. Можно прекрасно обойтись и без него.

Я использовал массив размером 16 байт, чтобы был всего один вызов `Encoding.GetString` вместо двух. Всё во имя уменьшения количества аллокаций. Но при этом нужен второй массив для изменённых данных с `specialSybmol`.

Вместо `StringBuilder` я использовал интерполяцию. В последних версиях дотнета она сильно оптимизирована и внутри используется буфер, устраняющий лишние аллокации памяти. Суть та же, что и в стрингбилдере.
Конечно, вызовы `BitConverter.ToString`, `Encoding.GetString` всё равно создают промежуточные строки, что на файлах больших размеров (гигабайты) приведёт к сборкам мусора.
Можно код полностью переписать, избавившись от этих аллокаций. Но вряд ли кто-то будет использовать на практике такой метод для представления файлов в hex-виде.

---

На заметку: в WinForms есть [ByteViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.byteviewer?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) - показывает данные в желаемом формате.